# GooglePlayServicesUtil Google Play Store is missing

Tags: android, maps

I am developing google maps application using Android 4.4 (google play services version 13), and I have followed the steps from the android site to setup google play services. When I run the application I get the error as

> GooglePlayServicesUtil  Google Play Store is missing

and a runtime error

> NullpointerException at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1410).

Please help me as I have done enough research to fix it but everytime I fix I get a new error.

Thanks

Comment: are you debugging on emulator...? Create google emulator (if yes)

Comment: I have used simulator with Google Api 4.4 and have set Lat/long values in DDMS but still no map is coming up except zoomin/zoomout button.In the logcat I see "Google Maps Android API v2 only supports devices with OpenGL ES 2.0 and above". I want the map to load in simulator  hence please help.